# Change text received from sql query in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am using a listview in asp.net and inside this listview I have a listbox that gets filled with data using my query. Some of the values that are in the listbox are empty. Is there a way to get the data that is empty and change it to "(Blank)"?

ASP.NET

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="FormTitleDataSource" 
    DataTextField="FormTitle" DataValueField="FormID" 
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("FormID") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="true">

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="FormTitleDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ORHP_Dev03182014ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT FormTitle, FormID FROM Core.Form_Lkup ORDER BY FormTitle">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Or does anyone know a way to use the select statement to change the empty strings without changing the value in the table.(using it for an application)

Comment: In Oracle, you could do `select NVL(FormTitle, '(Blank)')`. Not sure if there's an equivalent syntax for SQL Server (NVL stands for No Value, it's a function that replaces null with a specified value.)

Comment: post up your sql so we can offer a sql based solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried writing it into your SQL statement?

```
SELECT DISTINCT case when FormTitle = '' then '(Blank)' else FormTitle end as FormTitle, FormID FROM Core.Form_Lkup ORDER BY FormTitle
```

Comment: I forgot to end my case statement...fixed

Answer (score 1):

Add `OnDataBound="ListBox1_DataBound"` to your `ListBox` control:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" OnDataBound="ListBox1_DataBound" DataSourceID="FormTitleDataSource" 
    DataTextField="FormTitle" DataValueField="FormID" 
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("FormID") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="true">
```

Then add this method in codebehind:

```
protected void ListBox1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem i in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        if (i.Value == "")
            i.Text = "Blank";
    }
}
```